# How to group a list of list that matches certain condition

Tags: algorithm, elixir

I have a list of list.

```
[
  [4, 5, 6], 
  [5, 6, 7], 
  [8, 9, 10], 
  [20, 21, 22],
  [22,23,24]
]
```

if the upper_bound(5) of [5,6,7] is less than or equal to lower_bound(6) of [4,5,6] then grp them together and the final list should look like this.

```
[
  [
    [4, 5, 6], 
    [5, 6, 7]
  ],
  [8, 9, 10],
  [ 
    [20, 21, 22],
    [22,23,24]
  ]

]
```

How can i do this?

Comment: I'm a little confused. Have you mixed `upper_bound` and `lower_bound`?

Comment: @AstridE. in a list `[6,7,8]` , isnt the `upper_bound` 6 and `lower_bound` 8 ? or did i get this wrong?

Comment: Upper bound should denote the largest value in your set (as in "there are no values in this set greater than the upper bound"); and vice versa for the lower bound. I'm not sure which source is the most accurate to refer to here, but e.g. [Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/UpperBound.html) has a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer assumes that the items are always sequential, as in your example, and that no list completely contains another list.

First, it would be better to work with [Ranges](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Range.html), so we first convert the lists to ranges.

Then we can write a recursive algorithm `group_ranges/1`, which checks each range with its predecessor. If it overlaps (using [`Range.disjoint?/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Range.html#disjoint?/2)), add it to the group. If it doesn't overlap, start a new group.

Finally, since you want non-overlapping ranges to stand alone rather than be in a group of one, we handle that case once the grouping has completed. You could also convert the ranges back to lists at this stage, if that was a strict requirement.

```elixir
defmodule Example do
  def run do
    [[4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10], [20, 21, 22], [22, 23, 24]]
    |> Enum.map(fn [head | tail] -> head..List.last(tail) end)
    |> group_ranges()
    |> Enum.map(fn
      [single] -> single
      group -> group
    end)
  end

  def group_ranges([current | rest]), do: do_group_ranges(rest, [current], [])

  defp do_group_ranges([], group, grouped) do
    Enum.reverse([Enum.reverse(group) | grouped])
  end

  defp do_group_ranges([current | rest], [prev | _] = group, grouped) do
    if Range.disjoint?(current, prev) do
      # Create a new group
      do_group_ranges(rest, [current], [Enum.reverse(group) | grouped])
    else
      # Add to existing group
      do_group_ranges(rest, [current | group], grouped)
    end
  end
end
```

Result:

```elixir
iex(1)> Example.run
[[4..6, 5..7], 8..10, [20..22, 22..24]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the number of resulting lists is less than 32, grouping by `Range` would work.

```elixir
input
|> Enum.reduce(%{}, fn list, acc ->
  {min, max} = Enum.min_max(list)

  acc |> Map.keys() |> Enum.reduce_while(nil, fn 
    mn..mx, _ when min >= mn and min <= mx and max >= mn and max <= mx -> 
      {:halt, Map.update(acc, mn..mx, & [list | &1])}
    mn..mx, _ when min >= mn and min <= mx -> 
      {:halt, acc |> Map.delete(mn..mx) |> Map.put(mn..max, [list | Map.get(acc, mn..mx)])}
    mn..mx, _ when max >= mn and max <= mx ->
      {:halt, acc |> Map.delete(mn..mx) |> Map.put(min..mx, [list | Map.get(acc, mn..mx)])}
    _, _ -> {:cont, nil}
  end) || Map.put(acc, min..max, [list])
end)
|> Map.values()
|> Enum.map(&Enum.reverse/1)
```

If the expected number of lists is greater than 32 and the sorting must be preserved, the solution would be way more cumbersome.